# sending a safe html with django emailmessage

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-email

Good day, I'm trying to send a html in django email, pls what more can I added to the code.
the email sending is functioning well but it still shows the html tags.

```
from celery import task
from django.template.loader import render_to_string, get_template
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from orders.models import Order


@task
def payment_completed(order_id):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)

    subject = f'Testing html sending'
    message = render_to_string('orders/order/pdf.html', {'order':order})
    email = EmailMessage(
        subject,
        message,
        'youremai@gmail.com',
        [order.email, 'youremai@gmail.com']
    )
    email.content_subtype = 'html'
    email.send()
```

I've tried `render_to_string` and `get_template`
same result

[image: this is what i get in my mail.(showing HTML tags)]

Comment: could ou show what you see in your email? because it looks like your sending email function looks fine.

Comment: ok, i'm gonna add it to the post

Comment: could you also show your get_template code that you tried?

Comment: it was still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [EmailMultiAlternatives](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types) instead of `EmailMessage`, and code may look like this

```
email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    subject,
    message_plain_text,
    'youremai@gmail.com',
    [order.email, 'youremai@gmail.com']
)
email.attach_alternative(message, 'text/html')
email.send()
```

Comment: can i render to string with emailmultialternative?